# Yet another Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with this code snippet? I've looked through the many similar questions, but cannot find anything useful.

```
 $('div.editable').live('click', function() {
     editEl = $(this);
     $('#p-editor').hide();
     $(editEl).addClass('editing');
     $('#div-editor').show();
     $('#div-editor textarea').val($(editEl).html());
 });
```

Chrome developer console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function   myJavascript.js
(anonymouse function)                             myJavascript.js
fire                                              jquery-1.7.2.js
self.fireWith                                     jquery-1.7.2.js
jQuery.extend.ready                               jquery-1.7.2.js
DOMContentLoaded                                  jquery-1.7.2.js
```

Comment: Looks to me like something is undefined.  Find out which thing is undefined, and you have your answer.

Comment: I thought I was using...     <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

Comment: [.live( events, handler ): version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your code your jQuery 1.9.1 is getting overwritten by an older version.

Comment: @Josh: You mean a newer one, don't you?  "Removed in 1.9" means it's not in 1.9.1 anyway.

Comment: The console log is throwing errors from jquery-1.7.2.js, but Maxcot posted a script tag loading 1.9.1. That would lead me to believe there are two conflicting jquery declarations. But I'm tired, so who knows! haha

Comment: Yep, found a reference to 1.7.2 which I have now removed, but no improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is

```
jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards.
```

use this

```
 $('div.editable').on('click', function(){});
```

instead.

If you will see [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) it `.live()` categories is something like bellow.

```
Categories: Deprecated > Deprecated 1.7 | Events > Event Handler Attachment | Removed
```

Comment: Note that this usage of `on` doesn't delegate the event!

Comment: I think there is `delegate` function for that only.

Comment: No, `on` can delegate the events. `$('staticParentElement').on('event', 'selector', fn)`